# How to change remote for syncing in VS Code?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I used to fork a repo on GitHub and then clone my fork, and be in `origin`.

Recently I've been cloning the original repo and then using `hub fork`, and now my remote has my username instead of origin. (I understand why this is happening, that's not my question).

I can use `git push my_username master` in the command line. But I'd rather use the sync button/commands in VS Code. But that's trying to sync with the origin, which of course I don't have permission to push to.

How do I switch it to push to my fork? I actually got it to work once, but it was by a bunch of accidental clicking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the repository settings. The link to them is located under the Team Explore Tab -> Settings -> Repository Settings.  At the bottom of that area under remotes you can specify the remote origin for push and fetch.

UPDATE: The above is for VS 2015 GIT settings. This is different for VS Code.  In the Source control area there is three dots (...), click on these to get to the more options including the remote origin.  I don't have VS Code so I can't help you after that point.  Hopefully the documentation will guide you further if you need help.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol

Comment: I don't understand, is this on the GitHub website, or in VSCode? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: My bad.  I was assuming VS 2105 and VS code had the same interface with GIT.  I'll post an update.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's an easier way, but I couldn't figure it out within VS Code. I settled on just swapping the names and urls around so that the default remote that VS Code was pushing to would be the one I wanted.

I used the git commands below.

```
git remote rename oldname newname
git remote set-url newname myurl
```